# Is it possible to connect iPhone to Sound In port on PC running Windows 7?

Tags: iphone, audio, windows, hardware

Is it possible through a male/male cable to route audio from my iPhone 6 to my computer through the **Sound In** port?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  What's your end goal?  Are you simply trying to play music from your iPhone 6 to your HP PC?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the iPhone 6's headphone port to connect a male to male mini-stereo cable to a line-in/microphone port on a PC. Since you are going from digital to analog to analog to digital, you should expect the sound quality to be fairly poor.